# Selecting text element having specific style color

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have a scraping task to do in which I have to collect some articles. I know that I only need some paragraphs that are in red (`#FF0000`). Is there a way to use the Selenium WebDriver to extract only those colored in this colour? Through all the pages that I've to scrape, the only attribute that is always the same is the text color.

For example, in the following URL: https://www.boatos.org/saude/ivermectina-mata-covid-dois-dias-dose-unica.html

I want the webdriver to returns me just the following paragraph that is originally in painted in red:

> Versão 1: “IVERMECTINA REALMENTE MATA COVID-19 EM 2 DIAS COMPROVA ESTUDO”. Versão 2: “Cientistas descobriram que dose única de ivermectina pode remover todo o RNA do novo coronavírus em um período de 48 horas. Mesmo no primeiro dia, a redução do material genético do vírus é significativo”.

Comment: //span[@style='color: #ff0000;'] Would be a simple xpath.

Answer (score 0):

To print the text *Versão 1: “IVERMECTINA REALMENTE MATA COVID-19 EM...* you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.boatos.org/saude/ivermectina-mata-covid-dois-dias-dose-unica.html")
  print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span[style] > em").text)
  ```
- Using `xpath` and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.boatos.org/saude/ivermectina-mata-covid-dois-dias-dose-unica.html")
  print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@style]/em").get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```

---

Ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and `get_attribute()`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.boatos.org/saude/ivermectina-mata-covid-dois-dias-dose-unica.html")
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span[style] > em"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.boatos.org/saude/ivermectina-mata-covid-dois-dias-dose-unica.html")
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@style]/em"))).text)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Versão 1: “IVERMECTINA REALMENTE MATA COVID-19 EM 2 DIAS COMPROVA ESTUDO”. Versão 2: “Cientistas descobriram que dose única de ivermectina pode remover todo o RNA do novo coronavírus em um período de 48 horas. Mesmo no primeiro dia, a redução do material genético do vírus é significativo”.
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240245/how-to-retrieve-the-text-of-a-webelement-using-selenium-python/55241232#55241232)

---

### References

Link to useful documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416048/difference-between-text-and-innerhtml-using-selenium/55902072#55902072)